# Are portable USB DVD drives equally capable as SATA drives for ripping DVD's?

Tags: dvd, video-conversion, ripping

I'm currently archiving my physical DVD collection to a media server.

My desktop PC currently has a DVD drive but it's awkward to get at due to where the PC lives under my desk. I'm thinking about buying a portable DVD drive with a long enough cable so I can sit the drive on my desk within arms reach and rip away whilst I work and do other stuff.

I'm using SlySoft's AnyDVD and DVDFab to defeat any protection mechanisms that may be present on a DVD.

Are portable DVD drives - connected via a USB cable - equally capable of ripping DVD's as drives that are attached to SATA interfaces whilst using software such as AnyDVD or DVDFab?

Are there any commands or capabilities of DVD drives attached via USB that don't translate well (such as to defeat protection mechanisms), or work at all due to the USB to the SATA adapter (presuming that the drive inside the case has a SATA interface).

The reason that I ask is that I'm guessing these types tools must work at a fairly low level to get past the copy-protection mechanisms and that USB just adds a layer of difficulty.

Comment: I don't know if speed is of importance to you, but it's worth noting that it will likely take longer over USB vs. SATA. Granted the speed is going to be limited more by the RPMs of the DVD than the speed of the interface, but you might want to look into that.

Comment: @nhinkle - speed isn't a big deal, I'm very patient.

Comment: usb is a transport mechanism like sata is a transport mechanism. The drives on the other end work by the commands they are given over the transport mechanism which is relatively invisible to actual operation.